# Permission error by execute bash script via php shell_exec

Tags: php, linux, bash, sed, shell-exec

I try to insert line to `/etc/ppp/chap-secret` file via `bash script` what should run with `php shell_exec`.

I hope that I am on right way *or is there a better way*?
whatever my work is like below,

`/var/www/test.php:`

```
<?php echo shell_exec("cd /etc/ppp; bash test.sh"); ?>
```

`/etc/ppp/test.sh:`

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i "/IP addresses/a client123* pw123123 192.168.0.101" chap-secrets
```

I also added `www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/ppp/test.sh to sudoers.`

I get this `error`:

> sed: couldn't open temporary file ./sedXym2Nn: Permission denied

from terminal all works fine, but I need it from admin web via button click.

How to fix permissions error and get this process?

Comment: Granting your web server write access to system files is extremely ill-advised.

Answer (score 1):

Granting a web server access to system files sure seems reckless, but at least you are using a wrapper script to prevent the server from running arbitrary commands with super user privileges. That being said:

You have given `www-data` sudo access to `/etc/ppp/test.sh` without password, but you are not executing the command with sudo from your `shell_exec` function.

Calling `shell_exec("cd /etc/ppp;` **sudo** `bash test.sh");` should do the trick.